# XSL 1.0: Count Nods with specific beginning of the node name

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i need to count nods of a XML file. The nods are starting all with a specific character ('S'). How can i count all of those nods starting with 'S'.

For example i have this file

```
<root>
    <G_Group1>
        <S_DAS>
            <D_Name>Boot</D_Name>
            <D_Speed>10</D_Speed>
        </S_DAS>
        <S_GRU>
            <D_Name>Bike</D_Name>
            <D_Speed>3</D_Speed>
        </S_GRU>
        <G_HEL>
            <S_LOR>
                <D_Color1>Green</D_Color1>
                <D_Color2>Blue</D_Color2>
            </S_LOR>
        </G_HEL>
    </G_Group1>
    <G_Group2>
        <S_HUZ>
            <D_Name>Boot</D_Name>
            <D_Speed>10</D_Speed>
        </S_HUZ>
        <S_HUZ>
            <D_SPE>Bike</D_SPE>
        </S_HUZ>
        <S_LIL>
            <D_BER>Green</D_BER>
            <D_KLA>Blue</D_KLA>
        </S_LIL>
    </G_Group2>
</root>
```

in this case i would count 6.

```
S_DAS, S_GRU, S_LOR, S_HUZ, S_HUZ, S_LIL
```

Can anyone may help me?

Thanks in advance
Florian

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Input xml is not well formed, set the root element.

Comment: Thank you. 
Actually i don't know how to count them if i don't know in which depth they are. i already use count like this: <xsl:value-of select="count(/G_Group1" />. This would be ok and then i could sum up all variables.
But i will not know in which depth the node starting with "S" will be.

Comment: Thanks Rudramuni TP just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count *elements* whose name starts with "S", you can use:

```
count(//*[starts-with(name(), 'S')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Count like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::*[substring(name(),1,1)='S'])"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: great Rudramuni TP. This looks good i will give a try and provide feedback.
is there also an approach to to thsi with the generated output file? i have read something about RTF but as far as i understood this is only possible if you use Version 1.1

Comment: it doesn't work for me.
`code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <Value>
   <xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::*[substring(name(),1,1) eq 'S'])" />
  </Value>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
`
ERROR:  'Syntaxerror in "count(descendant::*[substring(name(),1,1) eq 'S'])".'

Any idea?

Comment: java -jar "saxon9h.jar" <input xml> <xslt> > <output name>  like this command line needs to give.

Comment: ok i will look for the jar. currently i'm useing Orangevolt XSLT for Eclipse

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 1.0, but the answer's syntax requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @michael Sir, is 'substring()' is xslt2?

Comment: No, the `eq` operator is XPath 2.0.